# Executar comando para cada coluna de uma data.frame

Tags: r, for, data.frame

Olá, tenho uma **data.frame (df)** 8 linhas x 8 colunas. Estou chamando as colunas de "ST[i]".

```
df <- structure(list(ST1 = c(58.69, 58.5, 58.5, 58.69, 58.69, 
58.5, 58.69, 58.69), ST2 = c(68.7, 68.42, 68.42, 68.7, 
68.7, 68.42, 68.7, 68.7), ST3 = c(69.15, 69.15, 68.83, 
69.15, 69.15, 69.15, 69.15, 69.15), ST4 = c(78.99, 
80.29, 78.99, 77.7, 78.99, 80.29, 78.99, 77.7), ST5 = c(75.65, 
75.65, 75.65, 72.57, 71.07, 68.14, 66.7, 66.7), ST6 = c(71.35, 
71.35, 79.83, 86.38, 83.09, 87.49, 87.49, 78.76), ST7 = c(73.61, 
72.48, 78.22, 102.06, 82.33, 79.97, 112.48, 91.39), ST8 = c(77.57, 
77.57, 77.57, 77.57, 77.57, 77.57, 77.57, 79.17)), .Names = c("ST1", 
"ST2", "ST3", "ST4", "ST5", "ST6", "ST7", "ST8"), row.names = 122:129, class = "data.frame")
```

Eu preciso executar um comando `waveslim::mra()` para cada uma dessas colunas.
O resultado deste comando, para cada coluna, será uma **list** com 12 vetores. Portanto, o produto final será 8 *lists*, cada *list* com 12 vetores.

Posso fazer, por exemplo:

```
dwc_ST1 <- mra(ST1, wf = "la8", method = "dwt", J=3, boundary = "reflection"
dwc_ST2 <- mra(ST2, wf = "la8", method = "dwt", J=3, boundary = "reflection")
...
dwc_ST8 <- mra(ST8, wf = "la8", method = "dwt", J=3, boundary = "reflection")
```

Mas seria muito bom se simplificasse isso. Pensei no `for()`, em algo como:

```
names_dwc <- as.character(rep(NA, ncol(df)))
for (k in 1:ncol(df)){
  names[k] <- paste('dwc_ST', k, sep = "")
  dwc_ST[k] <- mra(df[ ,k], wf = "la8", method = "dwt", J=3, boundary = "reflection")
  }
```

Mas tem aparecido:

> Error in ST[k] <- mra(df,[ , k], wf =
>   "la8",  :    object 'dwc_ST' not found

Eu pensei que eu teria solucionado este problema criando essas 8 ST's, com a linha (que utilizei acima):

> names[k] <- paste('dwc_ST', k, sep = "")

Parece que não estou sabendo como criar os arquivos para serem gerados os resultados.
Alguém sabe me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Qual o resultado esperado? Seriam 8 listas com 11 ou 12 vetores ou 1 lista com 88 ou 96 vetores? Além disso, seria bom você disponibilizar seu conjunto de dados, ou uma parte dele (utilize o comando `dput`), para o seu problema ser reproduzível. Por último, ao utilizar funções que não fazem parte do `R base`, indique no início do seu código qual o pacote necessário

Comment: Ok, obrigado pelas instruções, cara.

Comment: O produto será 8 listas (uma para cada coluna) com 12 vetores cada lista. Total: 96 vetores.
O mra() é do pacote "waveslim".
Enfim, a data.frame tem 2048 linhas. Usando o dput() estou colando as 8 primeiras linhas.

Comment: Para ficar mais fácil, coloque o resultado do `dput` na sua pergunta.

Comment: Rafael, segui suas instruções, apaguei meus comentários e melhor expliquei na pergunta acima. Meus dados originais têm 2048 linhas. Adaptei para 8 linhas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso em uma linha com `lapply`:

```
dwc_ST <- lapply(df, mra, wf = "la8", method = "dwt", J=3, boundary = "reflection")
```

O resultado é uma lista com os cálculos para cada coluna:

```
str(dwc_ST, max.level = 1)
List of 8
 $ ST1:List of 4
 $ ST2:List of 4
 $ ST3:List of 4
 $ ST4:List of 4
 $ ST5:List of 4
 $ ST6:List of 4
 $ ST7:List of 4
 $ ST8:List of 4
```

Se você fizer questão de renomear os objetos da lista para `dwc_ST1`, `dwc_ST2` etc:

```
names(dwc_ST) <- paste0("dwc_", names(dwc_ST))
```

E se você não quiser os objetos em uma lista, e sim cada um deles separadamente na área de trabalho (o que não recomendo), basta usar `list2env`:

```
list2env(dwc_ST, envir = globalenv()) # mas não recomendo
```

Comment: Valeu, Carlos! O resultado foi ótimo!
Como em minha próxima etapa plotarei as combinações das listas, e dos vetores por lista, ainda não sei se uma lista com mais de um nível é melhor para fazer essas combinações e devo mantê-la grande assim, ou se devo separá-la em várias listas.

Answer (score 4):

No seu código, você cria o objeto `names_dwc` e não o utiliza dentro do `for`. No caso `names_dwc[k] <- paste('dwc_ST', k, sep = "")` cria apenas um vetor de `character`e não cria os objetos `dwc_ST` como você pensou. Para isso, existe a função `assign`, que atribui um valor para um nome. Segue abaixo código:

```
names_dwc <- as.character(rep(NA, ncol(df)))
for(k in 1:ncol(df)){
  names_dwc[k] <- paste('dwc_ST', k, sep = "")
  assign(names_dwc[k], mra(df[,k], wf = 'la8', method = 'dwt', J = 3, boundary = 'reflection'))
}
```

Comment: Xará, perfeito cara!
Parece que o problema foi manter as listas que iam sendo criadas, e *assign()* era a solução, certo?
Precisei, de todo jeito, criar o vetor de caracteres *dwc_ST[k]*, antes do *for()*.
Obrigado!

Comment: Quem bom que a solução ajudou.